# Making a query into a XML RAW

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, aggregate

I'm using transact SQL and I got these tables...

```
main.locality - id,locality
main.job - id,jobs
main.person - name,surname,jobid,localityid,salary,gender
```

I need to get this output (XML RAW) PS. 
the first row is the average salary of all jobs
the second row is the average salary of all females
the third row is the average salary of all males
the fourth row is the average salary of that job and female
the fifth row is the average salary of that job and males

```
<row Average="19827" /> 
<row gender="F" Average="19835" /> 
<row gender="M" Average="19819" /> 
<row job="C# Developer" Average="20941" /> 
<row job="C# Developer" gender="F" Average="20845" />
<row job="C# Developer" gender="M" Average="21027" />
```

Can someone help me to make the query, please?

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking:

```
-- 1. SAMPLE DATA
DECLARE @locality TABLE (localityid int, locality int);
DECLARE @job TABLE (id int, Job varchar(100));
DECLARE @person TABLE 
(
  name varchar(100), 
  surname varchar(100),
  jobid int,
  localityid int,
  salary money,
  gender char(1)
);

INSERT @locality VALUES (1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 35), (4, 1000);
INSERT @job VALUES (1, 'C# Developer'), (2, 'DBA');
INSERT @person VALUES 
('joe', 'blow', 1, 1, 100000, 'M'),
('Sally', 'Doe', 1, 2, 135000, 'F'),
('Sue', 'Smith', 2, 2, 115000, 'F'),
('Kyle', 'Jones', 2, 3, 107500, 'M')
; 

-- 2. SOLUTION:
SELECT gender = NULL, job = NULL, average = AVG(p.salary)
FROM @person p
UNION ALL
SELECT p.gender, job = NULL, average = AVG(p.salary) 
FROM @person p
JOIN @job j ON p.jobid = j.id
GROUP BY p.gender
UNION ALL
SELECT gender = NULL, job = j.job, average = AVG(p.salary) 
FROM @person p
JOIN @job j ON p.jobid = j.id
GROUP BY j.Job
UNION ALL
SELECT p.gender, j.Job, average = AVG(p.salary)
FROM @person p
JOIN @job j ON p.jobid = j.id
GROUP BY p.gender, j.Job
FOR XML RAW;
```

Returns:

```
<row average="114375.0000" />
<row gender="F" average="125000.0000" />
<row gender="M" average="103750.0000" />
<row job="C# Developer" average="117500.0000" />
<row job="DBA" average="111250.0000" />
<row gender="F" job="C# Developer" average="135000.0000" />
<row gender="M" job="C# Developer" average="100000.0000" />
<row gender="F" job="DBA" average="115000.0000" />
<row gender="M" job="DBA" average="107500.0000" />
```

Comment: Hi, good approach, +1 from my side (and I borrowed your sample data, thx for this). My answer shows a much easier approach using `ROLLUP`, might be interesting for you...

Comment: Very well done shnugo. I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

This is [a job for `ROLLUP`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx)

(I borrowed Alan Burstein's sample data - thank you!)

```
-- 1. SAMPLE DATA
DECLARE @locality TABLE (localityid int, locality int);
DECLARE @job TABLE (id int, Job varchar(100));
DECLARE @person TABLE 
(
  name varchar(100), 
  surname varchar(100),
  jobid int,
  localityid int,
  salary money,
  gender char(1)
);

INSERT @locality VALUES (1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 35), (4, 1000);
INSERT @job VALUES (1, 'C# Developer'), (2, 'DBA');
INSERT @person VALUES 
('joe', 'blow', 1, 1, 100000, 'M'),
('Sally', 'Doe', 1, 2, 135000, 'F'),
('Sue', 'Smith', 2, 2, 115000, 'F'),
('Kyle', 'Jones', 2, 3, 107500, 'M');


SELECT j.Job
      ,p.gender 
      ,AVG(p.salary) AS Average 
FROM @person AS p
INNER JOIN @locality AS l ON p.localityid=l.localityid
INNER JOIN @job AS j ON p.jobid=j.id
GROUP BY ROLLUP (gender,job)
ORDER BY job,gender
FOR XML RAW
```

The result

```
<row Average="114375.0000" />
<row gender="F" Average="125000.0000" />
<row gender="M" Average="103750.0000" />
<row Job="C# Developer" gender="F" Average="135000.0000" />
<row Job="C# Developer" gender="M" Average="100000.0000" />
<row Job="DBA" gender="F" Average="115000.0000" />
<row Job="DBA" gender="M" Average="107500.0000" />
```